# Apache 1 virtual host definition listening on 2 ips - how?

Tags: ip, virtualhost, bind, httpd

We have a couple of complex virtual host definitions in our httpd.conf file.

What I mean by that is:

```
<VirtualHost .....>
....
</VirtualHost>
```

What I mean by complex is that they are full of rewrite rules and such.

We would like to bind this virtual host on 2 ip addresses. Currently it is bound only to one.

Is it possible to bind a virtual host to 2 ip addresses using a single VirtualHost?

It would make things a lot easier to have a single one if we need to make changes in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to handle this is to extract the common bits into a separate file (e.g., `/path/to/foo`) and then `Include` it in your vhost defs:

```
<Vitrualhost ...>
  ServerName X
  DocumentRoot Y
  Include /path/to/foo
</Virtualhost>

<Vitrualhost ...>
  ServerName Z
  DocumentRoot A
  Include /path/to/foo
</Virtualhost>
```

Note: Do not put `/path/to/foo` somewhere that will be pulled in by a wildcard `Include` elsewhere.

Comment: we like this approach the best. keeps us from having to muck around with anames and such and keep the solution in apache's world. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can just place multiple IP/Port specifiers in the  definition, as described in [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost).

Example:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80 2.3.4.5:80 1.2.3.4:8080>
DocumentRoot /path/to/wherever
ServerName example.com
# Stuff goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

Just make sure you've got Apache configured with enough NameVirtualHost definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively, consider using name-based virtual hosts instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use...

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

..to bind to any IP on the server

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with the named virtual hosts, AND make the modification to the DNS so that both IPs have A records with the same hostname.